# What does one call an edge which is not a part of a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

The title says it all. To reiterate:

What does one call an edge which is not a part of a cycle?

Comment: One possible is a bridge

Comment: For a connected graph, ["bridge"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphBridge.html).

Comment: It depends. It could be a chord. If you specify what you mean, it could be another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In graph theory, we say that an edge $e$ is a *cut edge* if its removal causes the original graph to become disconnected.

If $G$ is a simple graph, then it can be shown that an edge $e$ is contained in a cycle if and only if $e$ is not a *cut edge* (or *bridge*). A full proof is provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729779/prove-that-an-edge-e-is-contained-in-a-cycle-iff-e-is-not-a-cut-edge-in-a-si). Thus, we usually call edges that are not part of a cycle a *cut edge* or a *bridge*.